# pandas plot timeseries can't show time in x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, time-series

I read from book that timeseries can plot base time, but when I plot some stocks information I want to show time on X axis, but there is nothing in x axis, this is my code, and the pic is my plot, as show on x axis, noting here, what wrong with it?

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import tushare as ts
import bs4

data = pd.DataFrame()
data = ts.get_hist_data('600048',start='2017-01-05')
data['close'].plot(style = 'r', lw=2.)
print(data.head())
# ( data / data.ix[0] * 100 ).plot(figsize =(8, 5))
plt.show()
```

its output:

```
             open   high  close    low     volume  price_change  p_change  
date
2018-05-18  13.63  13.89  13.89  13.52  433132.31          0.29      2.13
2018-05-17  13.65  13.92  13.62  13.58  417857.84         -0.03     -0.22
2018-05-16  13.85  13.93  13.64  13.60  489171.94         -0.32     -2.29
2018-05-15  13.77  13.97  13.96  13.61  472956.09          0.24      1.75
2018-05-14  13.83  14.00  13.73  13.51  488781.00          0.03      0.22
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0i7E.png)

Comment: There are numerous examples in the [Matplotlib Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html).  You can often find the plot features you want and how to do it by browsing/searching it  Here is one -.   [https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html#api-example-code-date-demo-py](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html#api-example-code-date-demo-py). There is probably a duplicate question here on SO..

Comment: Is the `date` index a datetime type or is it a string? ...http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html

Comment: the date type is 'objects':  dtype='object', name='date', length=332

Comment: thanks for your help, I have solved these problem